LAUNCH FILE PROBLEM
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): "package 'my_robot-controller' not found, searching: ['/home/maddy/ws_mobile/install/mobile_robot'
I have been trying to start a simulation of a quadcopter using this repo https://github.com/noshluk2/sjtu_drone
But i keep on getting this error while launching the launch file
Need help!!!!
